# Unable to receive mail sent via sendgrid

Tags: email, nginx, next.js, sendgrid

I'm creating a  contact form using Nextjs and SendGrid, according to this header status

```
    202
  {
  server: 'nginx',
  date: 'Thu, 08 Dec 2022 16:29:25 GMT',
  'content-length': '0',
  connection: 'close',
  'x-message-id': 'CaVdpVAURza6JrUF7yIQQA',
  'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io',
  'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
  'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf- 
   of, x-sg-elas-acl',
  'access-control-max-age': '600',
  'x-no-cors-reason': 
  'https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=600; includeSubDomains'
  }
```

the email is sent but I find nothing in my inbox,

and this error occurs in the terminal

```
API resolved without sending a response for /api/contact, this may result in stalled requests.
```

I don't know what mistake I've done but. I invite you to look at my code bellow:

API :

```
import sgMail from "@sendgrid/mail";

export default function handler(req, res) {


if (req.method !== "POST") {
    res.status(405).json({ message: "INVALID_METHOD" });
    return;
}


// Variables from the client side

var name = req.body.name;
var email= req.body.email;
var subject= req.body.subject;
var content = req.body.content;



// auto line break message
const message = content
    .replace(/\n/g, "<br>")
    .replace(/\r/g, "<br>")
    .replace(/\t/g, "<br>")
    .replace(/<(?!br\s*\/?)[^>]+>/g, ""); 



// giving the api key API
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.KEY_SENDGRID);


// Creating message
const sendGridMail = {
    to: "arotiana4612@gmail.com",
    from: "kaspersky2mahanaima@gmail.com",
    subject: subject,
    templateId: "d-b48909edf062437e8442f861a4c8be29",
    dynamic_template_data: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        subject: subject,
        content: message,
    }, 
};
// SENDING MESSAGE VIA SENDGRID
(async () => {
    try {
        
        await sgMail.send(sendGridMail)
                    .then((response) => {
                        console.log(response[0].statusCode)
                        console.log(response[0].headers)
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error(error)
                    })  
    } catch (err){
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({
            error:JSON.stringify(err),
            message: "ERROR_WITH_SENDGRID",
        });
        
    }
})();
```

}

And this is the method from the client side that from which I get the data:

```
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = async (formData) => {
  
 if (!isLoading) {
  setIsLoading(true);
  const response = await fetch("/api/contact", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(formData),
  });

  const result = await response.json();
   
 
  setIsLoading(false);
  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log("error sending email:",result);
  } else {
    console.log("ok");
  }
    return result;
  
}
```

};

I want to receive the mail in my inbox.  Your help would be very appreciated,  I'm strugling

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @notDarkMatter , I've look around  the whole web an foud that the problem was not from my code, it appears to come from account verification from SendGrid. It was too long for me and I switched to nodemailer

Comment: Yes, same issue. Moved to a different provider.